# storage event - url property - what is it for?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, communication, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to write cross-tab communication based on localstorage events and i found that there is uri/url property describing what origin made this change, but... Isn't it like ONLY your own domain can change anything? Whats the point of property which is always equal to your domain, even port is the same?